# How doI read files in a systematic manner in R

Tags: r

I have a folder with 1000 .txt files, with names like file1.txt, file2.txt,....,and file1000.txt.
I want to extract a variable that is present in all the files. The problem is when reading the files, R reads the files from file1, file10, file11,...file1000 and then goes to file2, ...file299 and so on. How can I make the program read the files in a systematic manner (i.e. 1,2,3....,1000), so that it becomes easy to match the variable needed with the file number. I am using this piece of code:

```
  list_of_files <- list.files(path = ".", recursive = TRUE,
                            pattern = "\\.txt$", 
                            full.names = TRUE)
# Read all the files and create a FileName column to store filenames
DT <- rbindlist(sapply(list_of_files, fread, simplify = FALSE),
                use.names = FALSE, idcol = "FileName")
```

Answer (score 0):

If we want to order the files, do this with `mixedsort/mixedorder` and then read the files.   Also, instead of `sapply`, use `lapply`

```
library(gtools)
list_of_files <- list_of_files[mixedorder(basename(list_of_files))]
```